# does not load data through sqlloader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, ora-01843

I have a table in the oracle database: TABLESPACES and, columns DATA_TIME is  type: date. 
And a data file that wants to patch like this:

```
    ALTAIR          ;08-01-2019 10:33:28       ;SUB_DATA
    ALTAIR          ;08-01-2019 10:33:28       ;SUB_IDX
    ALTAIR          ;08-01-2019 10:33:28       ;SYSAUX
```

my control file looks like:

```
    load data
    infile '/home/oracle/space_monitor/logs/space_monitor.log'
    INTO TABLE TABLESPACES
    APPEND
    Fields terminated by ";"
    (
    DB "TRIM(:DB)",
    DATA_TIME "TRIM(:DATA_TIME)",
    NAME "TRIM(:NAME)"
    )
```

when trying to load data i have error:

```
    Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TABLESPACES, column DATA_TIME.
    ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

when I make changes to the control with TIMESTAMP file like this:

```
    load data
    infile '/home/oracle/space_monitor/logs/space_monitor.log'
    INTO TABLE TABLESPACES
    APPEND
    Fields terminated by ";"
    (
    DB "TRIM(:DB)",
    DATA_TIME "to_date(:TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')",
    NAME "TRIM(:NAME)"
    )
```

i have error:

```
    SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable :TIMESTAMP in SQL string for column DATA_TIME.
```

In my database oracle parameters:

```
    NLS_DATE_FORMAT like RR/MM/DD
    NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT like RR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SSXFF
```

Please help me.

Comment: In your 2nd code - `DATA_TIME "to_date(:TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')",` you need to replace `:TIMESTAMP` with `:DATA_TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use on of these sqlloder function (DATE fmt or TIMESTAMP fmt). 
Trim will be done automagicly

```
(
DB "TRIM(:DB)",
DATA_TIME  timestamp "DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS",
NAME "TRIM(:NAME)"
)
```

Comment: 3 Rows successfully loaded. Thx for help :)